# Pandas - shift() based on certain columns

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like this

```
date            group1    group2      not_used     val
2020-12-30        a          x          123         1
2020-12-31        a          x          124         2
2020-12-30        b          y          43          13
2020-12-31        b          y          425         16
```

I want to add column which is `yesterday_val` based on each `group` (combinations of `group1` and `group2`). I have other columns in my dataframe which are not relevant to what I am doing (`not_used`).My desired dataset would look like this

```
date            group1    group2      not_used     val       yesterday_val
2020-12-30        a          x          123         1             NaN
2020-12-31        a          x          124         2              1
2020-12-30        b          y          43          13            NaN
2020-12-31        b          y          425         16             13
```

I wonder whether there is a way to do this efficiently in Pandas. Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('group1')['val'].shift()`?

Comment: yes it works, thanks. if you post this as an answer I will accept.